# Agrupar y sumar todos los valores de una table en mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Tengo una tabla y necesito agrupar por motivo, calcular la suma de de todos los tiempos de ese motivo y el total de todos los tiempos de todos los motivos.

Pero no logro sacar el total de todos los tiempos. Os paso lo que tengo:

```
[{
    $addFields: {
        fechaInicio: {
            $dateFromString: {
                dateString: "$fechaInicioParo"
            }
        },
        fechaFin: {
            $dateFromString: {
                dateString: "$fechaFinParo"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        acumulado: {
            $subtract: ["$fechaFin", "$fechaInicio"]
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        acumulado: {
            $multiply: ["$acumulado", 2.7778e-7]
        },
    }
}, {}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$motivo",
        horasTotales: {
            $sum: "$acumulado"
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        horasAcumuladas: -1
    }
}]
```

En ese group no se como hacer para que me aparezca otra columna con los totales... ¿Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir un ejemplo de dato de entrada y la salida esperada? Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Por otro lado, estás trabajando con MongoDB, no existen *tablas* y mucho menos *columnas*, a lo que te refieres es a **colección** y **campo**. Saludos

Comment: Hola, disculpa la tardanza, he estado muy liado. Pude resolverlo con $facet... Aunque luego tuve que usar varios $unwind, pero lo pude solucional. Gracias por tu tiempo y de nuevo, disculpa la tardanza en responder.